Issues with adding Microsoft Extension to VS2019 Community
I'm trying to add the .NET Upgrade Assistant (.vsix) into VS2019 Community.  Using the "Extensions->Manage Extensions" menu doesn't appear to present any way for me to access the .vsix file that I've already downloaded from the MS website (FWIW, I've also marked it "unblocked" in Properties).  Double clicking on the .vsix file is apparently supposed to be a legit way of doing the installation.  Regardless of the (open or closed) state of VS, this action fails, with the following info appearing in the .log file:
7/20/2024 1:33:31 PM -  Extension is signed with a valid signature.
7/20/2024 1:33:31 PM - Searching for applicable products...
7/20/2024 1:33:31 PM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2019
7/20/2024 1:33:31 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
7/20/2024 1:33:31 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
My understanding is the the "Community" version should support this.
Is this a correct assumption?   If so, what is my next step?  I'm mystifryed! :)

VS2022 required, Prerequisites

Thanks for that link!  I missed that info somehow.  Now I guess I've got even More updating to do! :)
